# Firefox html external css not working

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I am creating a website using gedit. when I execute the html files from the file explorer, except the inline css, the external css doesn't seemto work. what is the problem? can anyone explain how to fix it?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Home </title>
  </head>
  <body id="back">
  <div id="Head">
  <left><img src="Logo.png" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"/></left>
  <h1> Sri Krishna Lending Library </h1>
  <p align="justify"><a href="index.html">Home </a> <a href="about.html">About us </a> <a href="books.html">Our Books </a> <a href="contact.html"> Contacts & Timings</a> <a href="http://goo.gl/forms/B5kLAzPAhy"> Library Reviews</a> <a href="article.html"> Author of the Month </a></p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  </div>

<div id="Page">

 <h2 align="center"> Welcome to Sri Krishna Lending Library's official website. </h2>
 <p align="center"> We are a library at Aziz Nagar 2nd street, Near Railway Border Road, Kodambakkam, chennai - 600 024 </p>
 <center>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;"><div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style><a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.trivoo.net/google-maps/" id="get-map-data">www.trivoo.net</a></div><script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:21,center:new google.maps.LatLng(13.047368339315124,80.22979016214481),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.047368339315124, 80.22979016214481)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>Sri Krishna Lending Library</b><br/>aziz nagar 2nd street<br/>600 024 Chennai" });google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script></center>

 <br>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div id="Footer">
 <p> Don't Forget to visit us! </p>
 <br>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? We would be of more help if you could post your code!

Comment: Is the `index.html` in the same folder as `styles.css`?

Comment: yeas, it is in the same folder.

Comment: Copy paste the code in my editor, and made my own `styles.css`. Its working fine. Can i see the content of your `styles.css`. Maybe its an error in the css code?

Comment: this is the link to the code: http://pastebin.com/GGF10CG8

Comment: It seems to be working just fine: http://i.imgur.com/YQbKhdp.png

Comment: You Click on the `index.html`, and then what happens? Is is possible for you to provide a screenshot?

Comment: it looks like this: http://imgur.com/0gYDDAl

Comment: I get roughly the same look, when I remove the `styles.css`. Meaning you mistyped the `styles.css` in your `index.html`, or you named the `styles.css` differently. Check your file names!

Comment: It worked right in windows firefox, it's not coming in ubuntu.

Comment: Where are you running these codes from? It might be a permission issue. Is it from a `NTFS` partition?

Comment: yes, and no. I first ran it in a ntfs partition, then copied the folder from it and pasted it in another folder in the home folder

Comment: Then i think its a permission issue. Right click, go the `rights` and give yourself read write permission. on the `styles.css`!

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of your permission tab?

Comment: http://imgur.com/7STXLrd

Comment: Change all the `access` part from `none` to `read/write`! and then click `Change permissions for enclosed files...`!

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Create a new file called `style.css` copy the content from `styles.css` to your newly created `style.css`. Delete/remove the file `styles.css`. And rename the `style.css` to `styles.css`. Then try it again!

Comment: why is it happening?

Comment: The `root`(administrator) mounted your ntfs partition, `styles.css` was in the NTFS partition, thus the file `styles.css` belongs to `root`. We will delete `styles.css`, create your own `styles.css`, thus making you the owner, and able to run it without issues.

Comment: Did it work? :D

Comment: it did not work

Comment: It worked!!! I am greatful to you.

Comment: I will turn my comment in to an answer could you be so kind as to accept it?

Comment: yes, I accept it.

Comment: Avoid having extended discussions in the comments section. The chat rooms are better suited for long and/or multiple exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission issue, as the file resided in a NTFS partition that was mounted by root.

The `root`(administrator) mounted your ntfs partition, `styles.css` was in the NTFS partition, thus the file `styles.css` belongs to root.

Create a new file called `style.css` copy the content from `styles.css` to your newly created `style.css`. Delete/remove the file `styles.css`. And rename the `style.css` to `styles.css`. Then It should work again!